# How many different triangles?

Tags: geometry

If $x$ is an integer and $2<x<7$, how many different triangles can be made with sides $2,7$ and $x$?

My attempt:

I immediately noticed that between $2$ and $7$, there are only $4$ integers, so $x$ can have $4$ different values and hence $4$ different triangles can be made. However, when I checked the answers, it said the answer is $1$. Why is this?

Comment: To get an intuition of this: draw a line of length 7, then, at one end of that line, a circle of radius 2. The side of lenght 2 has to have its second end on that line. Now draw a circle of radius $x$ with center at the other end of the length 7 line (insert the possible values you figured out). In order to get a triangle the two circles of radius 2 and $x$ have to intersect...

Comment: I assume that by "different triangles" you mean incongruent triangles. The answer depends on $x$. If $x=6$ the answer is $1$; there is a triangle with sides $2,7,6$ and all such triangles are congruent. For other values of $x$ the answer is $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the triangle inequality (which says that any two sides of a triangle combined must be longer than the third) to form three inequalities:

$$2 + 7 > x \implies x < 9$$
$$2 + x > 7\implies x > 5$$
$$x + 7 > 2~~\text{(which is always true for positive $x$)}$$

so that $x$ must be more than $5$ (or since $x$ is an integer, it must be at least $6$). Since $x < 7$, there is only one solution for $x$, namely $x = 6$.